# How to set plot styles using matlab2tikz?

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure, tikz

I am struggling with automating two different styles of plots. I would like to export a figure with matlab2tikz and then include it respectively to the style I define.

First a Matlab-Example:

```
    x = 0:10;
    y = 0:10;
    plot(x,y)
    matlab2tikz(myfile_FirstStyle.tikz,'extraCode',FirstStyle, 'height', '\fheight', 'width', '\fwidth','showInfo', false,'extraaxisoptions', ['style=FirstStyle']);
```

I am not sure, if this is even a possibility to create a style: 'extraaxisoptions', ['style=FirstStyle']
At least it didn't work.

Now follows my try in Latex:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
 \usepackage{grffile}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{tikzscale}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{tikz}                   

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 %%% Specific Style: FirstStyle

 \pgfplotsset{FirstStyle/.append style={ 
        width=\fwidth,
        height=0.70\fwidth,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        ylabel=$FirstStyle$,
        legend pos=north west,
        }   
        }

\newlength\fheight 
\newlength\fwidth   
\setlength\fheight{0.68\textwidth}
\setlength\fwidth{0.85\columnwidth}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{figure}

    \input{myfile_FirstStyle.tikz}

\caption{This is the FirstStyle}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to predefine the style of one's plots using Matlab2tikz? 
Thank you so much for your help, any idea is appreciated.
Praia